# How to solve error: cannot find symbol message.reply(...); Vertx point-to-point

Tags: java, vert.x

I have two java classes communicating using a vert.x `EventBus`.

I have a Productor.java class:

```
package TP1;

import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.eventbus.EventBus;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;

public class Productor extends AbstractVerticle 
{
    public void start() throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("> Launching Productor...");

        EventBus ebReady = vertx.eventBus();

        //Send ready message
        ebReady.send("canal-ready", "ready", messageReady -> {

            //If Consumer received the ready message
            if(messageReady.succeeded())
            {
                //Parse json response
                JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject(messageReady.result().body().toString());

                //Get answer value
                int answerValue = Calcul.factorial(jsonObject.getInteger("param"));

                String answer = Integer.toString(answerValue);

                messageReady.reply(answer);//ERROR HERE
            }
            else
                System.out.println("> No response!");
        });
    }
}
```

and a Consumer.java class:

```
package TP1;

import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.eventbus.EventBus;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;

public class Consumer extends AbstractVerticle 
{
    public void start() throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("> Launching Consumer...");

        String jsonString = "{\"class\":\"Calcul\",\"method\":\"factoriel\",\"param\":5}";
        JsonObject jsonObj = new JsonObject(jsonString);

        EventBus ebReady = vertx.eventBus();

        //Wait for ready message
        ebReady.consumer("canal-ready", messageReady -> {

            //Parse the ready message
            String readyString = messageReady.body().toString();

            //Make sure it's the ready message
            if(readyString.equals("ready"))
            {
                //Send json back (messageReady.succeeded())
                messageReady.reply(jsonObj, messageReadyReply -> {
                    System.out.println(messageReadyReply);
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I can't build the Productor class but have no problem with the Consumer one.

What's wrong with the `messageReady.reply(answer);` part in the Productor.java class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing a call to `result()` (see [here](https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/blob/3.8/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/AsyncResult.java#L36)) before getting the message and executing methods on it. However, you're using methods that have been deprecated in the 3.8 version ([example](https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/blob/3.8/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/eventbus/EventBus.java#L89)) and are missing from 4.0, so I would advise that you use the other signature instead.

Comment: I found out what I was doing wrong while writing the question... I was missing 
the .result() part in messageReady.result().reply(anser)

Comment: and to answer your question, the `messageReady.reply(jsonObj, ...` part worked well in the Consommateur class. So yeah, it is supposed to work.

Comment: Yeah I don't think I'm looking at the right code, because the `Message` interface doesn't have the methods you mention (`body()` and `result()`) https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/blob/7fc8a7a93a52be4172d862c90322b5d2d2e3c0cd/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/eventbus/Message.java#L34. Is the lib you're using on Github?

Comment: I installed vertx directly from their website https://vertx.io/ and I'm on Ubuntu.

Comment: Ok, I think Github has the 4.0 version while the site vends 3.8.5, must be why it was different. You're using a deprecated method on the server aren't you? https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/blob/3.8/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/eventbus/EventBus.java#L89 I guess you should move to the latest API instead